# Macro to to sum numeric values based on data within the same cell?

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to create either a formula or macro to sum a series of numbers within a single cell based on preceding non-numeric characters (using Excel 2010).

For example, I have a cell that reads:

`ABC1|HIJ2|ABC4|ABC3|DEF5|ABC2|DEF8|ABC5`

But I need it to read:

`ABC15|DEF13|HIJ2`

All relevant data comes in a single cell in a (mostly) random order, so the problem is two-tiered - first auto-alphabetize all data within the cell, second to sum all "ABCs," "DEFs," etc.

I've used the following code to (successfully) auto-alphabetize the data, but now I'm kinda at a loss as to where to go from here, as all of my googling suggests this sort of task needs a multi-cell solution.

```
Sub Macro()

Dim Rng As Range
Dim WorkRng As Range
Dim Arr As Variant
On Error Resume Next
Set WorkRng = Application.Selection
Set WorkRng = Application.InputBox("Range", xTitleId, WorkRng.Address, Type:=8)
Set objArrayList = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")
For Each Rng In WorkRng
Arr = VBA.Split(Rng.Value, "|")
For i = 0 To UBound(Arr)
    xMin = i
    For j = i + 1 To UBound(Arr)
        If Arr(xMin) > Arr(j) Then
            xMin = j
        End If
    Next j
    If xMin <> i Then
        temp = Arr(i)
        Arr(i) = Arr(xMin)
        Arr(xMin) = temp
    End If
Next i
Rng.Value = VBA.Join(Arr, "|")
Next
End Sub
```

Is there a way to do this while keeping the end result confined to a single cell?

Thank you in advance for anyone who takes the time to help.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please note, that this is not a free code-writing service. Yet, we are eager to help fellow programmers (and aspirants) writing their own code. Please read the help topics on [How do I Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You might also want to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and earn a badge while doing so. Afterwards, please update your question with the VBA code you have written thus far in order to complete the task(s) you wish to achieve (as the above cannot be solved with a formula).

Comment: Is it always three letters and then a number?

Comment: Yes, it always follows the same format of XYZ1 (alph-alpha-alpha-numeric)

Comment: I posted an answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a different approach (which does assume three letters plus number(s)). It assumes input in A1 and puts results in G1.

```
Sub x()

Dim v, vOut(), i As Long, n As Long, s As String, s1 As String, oSL As Object

v = Split(Range("A1"), "|")
ReDim vOut(1 To UBound(v), 1 To 2)

Set oSL = CreateObject("System.Collections.Sortedlist")
For i = LBound(v) To UBound(v)
    oSL.Add CStr(v(i)), Nothing
Next i

With CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    For i = 0 To oSL.Count - 1
        s1 = Left(oSL.GetKey(i), 3)
        If Not .Exists(s1) Then
            n = n + 1
            vOut(n, 1) = s1
            vOut(n, 2) = Val(Right(oSL.GetKey(i), Len(oSL.GetKey(i)) - 3))
            .Add s1, n
        Else
            vOut(.Item(s1), 2) = vOut(.Item(s1), 2) + Val(Right(oSL.GetKey(i), Len(oSL.GetKey(i)) - 3))
        End If
    Next i
End With

For i = 1 To n
    s = s & "|" & vOut(i, 1) & vOut(i, 2)
Next i

Range("G1") = Mid(s, 2)

End Sub
```

Comment: This is...perfect, actually. Thank you.